# Cambiar posicion div para version movil responsive css

Tags: html, css, responsive

Tengo varios div creados del estilo:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">Texto</div>
  <div class="column2">Casilla aceptar</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">Texto</div>
  <div class="column2">Boton</div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que en el caso de la version movil me cargase de la forma siguiente:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">Texto</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">Texto</div>
</div>
<div class="column2">Casilla aceptar</div>
<div class="column2">Boton</div>
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

[image: boceto]

Comment: ¿Podrías dejar una captura de lo que buscas? Es un poco difícil ver el efecto que quieres solo con el código. Quiero decir, para cambiar la estructura del html necesitarías algo más que css, pero algo solo visual sí podrías lograrlo solo con css

Comment: Me imagino que lo que quieres es saber cómo hacerlo sin cambiar el HTML,  sólo con CSS. ¿Podemos cambiar la estructura del HTML?

Comment: Quiero que se haga responsive, que cuando alguien entre desde el movil le salga esta organización:  https://ibb.co/z5zR9SK

Comment: Como bien te dicen, deja una imagen con el "paint" para ver la IDEA de lo que buscas, hay 2 formas de hacerlos, una es mediante -col- que cambiará en función del tamaño de pantalla y la otra MediasQuery

Comment: Ya he visto tu imagen, si estás usando boostrap, usa <div class="col-12  col-md-6"> Esto hará que si el tamaño es pequeño, use 12 (todo) y si es grande solo la mitad ->  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Comment: @EduBw Eso no reordenaría el contenido de la forma que quiere el usuario, porque se seguiría viendo en orden 1234, cuando en pantallas pequeñas quiere que se vea 1324.

Comment: Cierto, no me fijé en el ordenamiento.

Answer (score 5):

Una manera de conseguir esto sería cambiando un poco el HTML y usando FlexBox (para maquetar los elementos) y media queries (para detectar cuando estás en móvil y debe reorganizarse el contenido).

- Pon todos los elementos como descendientes del mismo padre
- Ponle `display: flex` y `flex-direction: column` al contenedor para que los elementos estén en vertical.
- Con media queries detecta añade un `order` para que se reordenen los elementos dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla (en el ejemplo de abajo he puesto 450px, pero puedes cambiarlo al valor que quieras).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando (dale a "Página completa" y cambia el tamaño de página para verlo):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column1 {
  width: 80%;
}

.column2 {
  width: 20%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 450px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .row .column1 {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .row .column2 {
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    Texto 1
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    Text 2
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <button>Aceptar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

En ventanas con un ancho de más de 450px (especificado por la media query), los elementos se ven así:

[image: ejemplo de ordenacion 1]

Mientras que si la pantalla es de como máximo 450px, se verán de este otro modo:

[image: ejemplo de ordenación 2]

Comment: Como comentario aparte, en general reordenar los elementos de una manera diferente a como están en el código puede presentar problemas de accesibilidad. Aunque puede que en este caso no importe mucho dependiendo del contexto/contenido.

Comment: Pero en tu resultado esta mostrando texto 1 y después la casilla de verificacion, yo queria primero los textos y luego la casilla y el botón

Comment: @David ¿has cambiado el tamaño de pantalla? Mi respuesta se ve diferente en pantallas grandes y pequeñas. En pantallas grandes se ve: Texto 1, casilla, Texto 2, botón. En pantallas de menos de 450px se ve: Texto 1, Texto 2, casilla, botón. Dale al botón de Ejecutar la demo, luego a "Página completa" y cambia el tamaño de la ventana para ver el efecto.

Comment: Vale correcto, lo he tratado de implementar pero claro, me transforma el diseño original que yo tengo. Te explico, es un formulario de contacto en tres columnas, el problema en responsive es que la tercera me rompe demasiado el diseño y son las que queria mover abajo. Te dejo capturas (https://ibb.co/5RyKR7W   -   https://ibb.co/Wv9ssMV)

Comment: @David he actualizado el ejemplo para que sea vea como la imagen (con filas en pantalla grande)

Comment: @David eso debería ir en la propia pregunta y no como comentario en una respuesta. Además, deberías añadir el código CSS y las bibliotecas (si usas alguna) para que podamos verlo. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta.